# What is the name of this trick-taking card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

Years ago, in the 70s, my aunt from Kentucky taught us a card game. She called it "Table".  I've found nothing on the internet but it seems similar to Oh Hell. You were dealt 1 card in the first round, 2 in the second, etc. up to 10 cards in the 10th round then back down to 1. Like Oh Hell, players bid on tricks and score points but only if they make their bid.  Unlike what I've seen of Oh Hell, if a player doesn't make their bid they go set and lose points. I would like to know the actual name of this game and also how it's scored.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Hell#Scoring), Oh Hell can have different variations each with different scoring. So I guess it would still be Oh Hell, just with your aunts preferred scoring method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that [Simon Klaver](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/20057/simon-klaver)'s comment referring to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Hell#Scoring) article on Oh Hell and its variations is the answer here. Although there's nothing on a version called "table."

Comment: Perhaps the aunt was religious enough not to want to say "H-E-Double-Toothpicks" ever time she talked about the game...

Comment: Is Oh Pshaw not a common name for this game? Seems like a better appropriate name than Table

Answer (score 0):

In Wizard, you score ten points for making your bid, plus ten points per trick that you bid.

If you don't get your exact bid, you lose ten points for each trick that you were off (either over or under).

The deal and play are the same as in Oh Hell. Wizard add two ranks of cards: four Wizards that win any trick, and four Jesters that lose any trick.

It's fun, but the scoring is much wilder (and favors strong hands too much, if you ask me).

Comment: (One difference between [the published version that I own of] Wizard and your description is that you only ascend in Wizard, and play until you can't deal more cards per player.)

Comment: So the score is always a multiple of 10?

Comment: That is correct.